# Colliding in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm currently developing a small 2D game. I have a script for the collisions so that I get a `Debug.Log()` whenever my character touches something. This is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collidable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ContactFilter2D filter;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Collider2D[] hits = new Collider2D[10];

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        //Collision Work
        boxCollider.OverlapCollider(filter, hits);
        for(int i=0; i<hits.Length; i++)
        {
            if(hits[i] == null)
                continue;
          
            OnCollide(hits[i]);


            hits[i] = null;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
    {
        Debug.Log(coll.name);
    }
}
```

I would like to get only 1 console log whenever my character is, for example, picking up, therefore, touching a chest and get a message what he picked up, but for as long as the character is touching the chest, the Logs won't stop flying.
How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if your box collider is trigger then  OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) not OnCollide(Collider2D col) . If is not trigger then OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2Dcollision)
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `flag` (a `boolean`) to call the method only once

At the top of the script, initialize a `boolean` variable `hasCollided` which is set to false on default.

```
private bool hasCollided = false;
```

Call the `OnCollide()` method only when the collision has not occurred yet and when the collision has occurred, set `hasCollided` to `true`.

```
protected virtual void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
{
    if(!hasCollided)
    {
        Debug.Log(coll.name);
        hasCollided = true;
    }
}
```

This calls the `OnCollide()` method only once.

Answer (score 0):

The official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapCollider.html) for `Collider2D.OverlapCollider` states that

> Get a list of all colliders that overlap this collider.

and you are checking that on `Update()` meaning your collision code get executed everytime there are any collider overlapping your `BoxCollider2D`

You should look into [Collider.OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) which gets called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider.

*However collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.*